# Can't run bash script in PHP

Tags: php, linux, bash, swi-prolog

I'm trying to run bash script in PHP but can't run it.
php -v

```
PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.2 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Jun 13 2012 17:19:58)
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
```

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 bit.

My php code:

```
    $cmd='/www/var/pl/bash.sh';
    $retval =-1;
    exec( $cmd, $output ); //executing the exec function.
    foreach( $output as $tmp ) 
    { 
        echo "$tmp <br>"; 
    };
```

bash.sh:

```
 #!/bin/bash
swipl --quiet -s /var/www/pl/ples.pl -g "f(R, gel), writeln(R),open('/var/www/pl/in.txt',write, Stream),
write(Stream, (R)),
nl(Stream),
close(Stream)" -t halt.
```

What am I doing wrong?

And I can run bash.sh in the Linux terminal.

Comment: Try preceding the shell script with "bash" - so have "bash /www/var/pl/bash.sh"

Comment: Change `$cmd` to `/www/var/pl/bash.sh 2>&1`. It still won't run, but might give you some insights about why it doesn't.

Comment: What errors are you seeing, if any? I assume your PHP isn't running in safe mode and that the exec command isn't specifically disabled?

Answer (score 5):

When you run the script in the terminal you are executing it under the account you are logged in to. You have a shell setup with a search path etc.

When php executes the script, it has not a shell setup, and runs under the webserver user account. When executing:

- make sure you have complete paths to your file,  `swipl` is not enough, it should be `/path/to/swipl`
- make sure the **webserver process** has enough access rights to get everything it needs.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it is either a path or permission problem; for example the user the web application runs as, has no idea where the `swipl` program is.

Add 2>&1 to the command line before `exec`'ing it, so that it tells you what the problem is. Or you can find the stderr output into the web server error log (or PHP error log; check its path and settings in php.ini).